# How can I write a JUnit test for a void function with 3 probabilities?

Tags: java, jpa, junit

Think that I can favorite movies in a website with a twitter-style toggle star button, but I can only have one favorite movie.

Probabilities:

1) When I have a favorite movie and decide to favorite a different movie, it will remove the favorite from the old one and will add a favorite to the new movie (Delete one row, insert one row).

2) I already favorited the movie. So when I clicked it again, it will be removed, the movie would be unfavorited (Delete one row).

T3) I have no favorite movie. When I click favorite for a movie, it will assign the movie as my favorite (Insert one row).

I have a single function in my backend java code for this 3 probabilities:

```
@PUT
@Path("/updateFavorite/{newMovieId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void updateFavorite(@PathParam("newMovieId") int newMovieId) {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory
            .createEntityManager();

    try {
        boolean removeFavorite = false;

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        MovieEntity newMovie = fetchMovieWithId(entityManager, newMovieId);

        int movieGenre = newMovie.getMovieGenre();

        if (favoriteMovieExists(entityManager, movieGenre)) {
            FavoriteMovieEntity existingFavoriteMovie = fetchFavoriteMovieWithGenre(
                    entityManager, movieGenre);
            // If existing movie and the current movie are the
            // same, than it is a 'remove favorite' click
            if (existingFavoriteMovie.getMovieId() == newMovie.getMovieId()) {
                removeFavorite = true;
            }
            entityManager.remove(existingFavoriteMovie);
        }
        // it is not already favorited, create a new favorite
        if (!removeFavorite) {
            FavoriteMovieEntity newFavoriteMovie = new FavoriteMovieEntity();
            FavoriteMoviePK newFavoritePK = new FavoriteMoviePK(getUser(),
                    movieGenre);

            newFavoriteMovie.setKey(newFavoritePK);
            newFavoriteMovie.setMovieId(newMovieId);

            entityManager.persist(newFavoriteMovie);
        }
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

I decided to write 3 test functions for each probability, but i am not sure how can I do without any value returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you basically want to try to do is create a defined(!) environment state, apply your function, check that the effect on the environment was as desired.

You can do this e.g. by creating a database already containing a user with a favorite movie, apply the function, check that afterwards another movie is the favorite movie by checking directly against the database. Using the `EntityManager` an in-memory database would be a good idea to use. Try to not use some development database for automated tests that is also accessed by other clients. Use something very local to your machine and something that can ideally be setup and teared down with each test (hence the recommendation for an in-memory database).

Another way is to mock parts of your code and make sure the appropriate callback are called. E.g. you could mock the `EntityManager` and make sure the persist and remove methods are called properly. A good framework for that would probably be [mockito](http://mockito.org/).

Giving your more concrete help (i.e. code) would require more input on how tests are currently performed and what the overall setup should be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write 3 test functions:

1. `testFavoriteExistReplace()`
2. `testFavoriteExistUnfavorite()`
3. `testFavoriteNotExistCreateNew()`

You have 2 options to do this:

- **without changing the backend code:** in your test functions call your `updateFavorite(movieId)` with different data and preset database configuration for all 3 probabilities; after the function passes **do not check the returned value, but check the database data**. There should be an answer whether your test is successful or not.
- **changing the backend code:** it may be convinient to split your `updateFavorite(movieId)` function into 3 small functions per each probability and test them separatelly. You can also **test not the database in this case but the decision, which your function logic made** on which of 3 probabilities is this.